# Scrollable custom view on pan gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer, custom-view

I am new to iOS, I am trying to create a scrollable custom view.

Basically on tapping on any of the icons in the screen, a custom view should pop up from botton. It should have button to expand to full screen or on pan gesture it should expanded to full screen. Here I a created a WF for better understanding.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYUq0.png)

edit: Changed to Cutom View from Action sheet in question.

Answer (score 1):

Action sheets don't have that level of customization. You'll have to make a custom view for this functionality.